# Initial value problem in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Write down an explicit formula for a function $u$ solving the initial value problem. $$\begin{cases}
 u_{t} +b \cdot Du +cu =0 & \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^{n} \times (0, \infty)\\
 u =g & \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \{t=0\}
 \end{cases}$$ Here $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are constants.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t >0$.

Let $w(s)=u(x+sb,t+s)$.

Therefore we have,
\begin{align}
   w'(s)+cw(s) & = 0\\
   \dfrac{dw}{ds}+cw & = 0\\
   e^{cs}\dfrac{dw}{ds} +c e^{cs}w & =0\\
   d(e^{cs}w) & =0\\
   e^{cs}w & =K,
  \end{align}where $K$ is a constant. $w(s)= Ke^{-cs}$.

When $s=-t$, we have $w(-t)=u(x-tb,0)=g(x-tb)$ and $K = w(-t)e^{-ct}$. Therefore $K =g(x-tb)e^{-ct}$. Then $u(x,t)=w(0)=K= e^{-ct}g(x-tb)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t>0$.